# Thread 5 : SIGABRT error while running the app in my device (Works fine in simulator)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Just started messing around with xcode 11.3.1 and I am pretty new to this . Now learned some things through a lot of tutorials and created an application which runs pretty good in the builtin simulator . But when i try to run the same app in my own device (iPhone 6s) it gives me an error saying as in the picture . Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: See the bottom right part of your screenshot? That's the console. Read it, there is a explaination about why it crashes. You can search for the error if needed.

Comment: The error message is very precise and tells you exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are using a microphone in your application without getting privacy access from the user.
You should add `Privacy - Microphone Usage Description` in your info.plist

Comment: Thank you Sir . As I said i'm pretty new to this whole interface but thank you for pointing out problem .

Answer (score 0):

The console in the bottom right of picture clearly describe the problem.